# Problem removing codeSubDirectories elements in sub-application

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have an ASP.NET application with a <codeSubDirectories> section in web.config.  My main project is in VB.NET but I have a CSCode subdirectory under App_Code written in C#.  Now for every new sub application I create I have to create a CSCode folder under App_Code.  Microsoft's documentation says there is a <clear /> element but I get an error when I add it to the sub application's web.config file.  What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.  Apparently Microsoft never got around the actually coding the <clear /> element for <codeSubDirectories>.  The online [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228265(VS.85).aspx#ctl00_WikiContent_headerTitle) mentions this in the Community Content section.

As a workaround I'm going to move the CSCode into a separate DLL.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt have the source code, you can create all subdirectories inside your App_Code subapplication, even with no content. Code works great, in the most cases.

References:

http://systemscenter.ru/avicodeenterprisedotnetmp2007manual.en/appendix-knowledgebase.htm